# On DataFrame.pivot(), different result with what I expected

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm referring to
[https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/main/doc/cheatsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN5jC.png).

[image]

As you can see, if I use `pivot()`, then all values are in row number 0 and 1.

But if I do use `pivot()`, the result was different like below.

DataFrame before `pivot()`:

[image]

DataFrame after `pivot()`:

[image]

Is the result on purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, the grey column (index of the row) is missing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable': list('aaabbbccc'), 'value': range(9)})
print(df)

# Output
  variable  value
0        a      0
1        a      1
2        a      2
3        b      3
4        b      4
5        b      5
6        c      6
7        c      7
8        c      8
```

Add the grey column:

```
df['grey'] = df.groupby('variable').cumcount()
print(df)

# Output
  variable  value  grey
0        a      0     0
1        a      1     1
2        a      2     2
3        b      3     0
4        b      4     1
5        b      5     2
6        c      6     0
7        c      7     1
8        c      8     2
```

Now you can pivot:

```
df = df.pivot('grey', 'variable', 'value')
print(df)

# Output
variable  a  b  c
grey             
0         0  3  6
1         1  4  7
2         2  5  8
```

Take the time to read [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/15239951)